# Чем отличаются эти записи?

Tags: php, mysql

Правильно ли я их понимаю??

```
1)$query="select pass from userlist where name='$_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER]'";

2)$query="select pass from userlist where name=$_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER]";

3)$query="select pass from userlist where name=$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']";
```

1) Это проверка значения переменной массива?

2) Не понимаю какое значение проверялось бы в name

3) Не понимаю почему не правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По синтаксису строк в PHP можно почитать в [официальной документации](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) (разделы "Простой синтаксис", "Сложный синтаксис");

Если поле name в таблице имеет текстовый тип, в запросе его значение необходимо обрамлять кавычками. Поэтому вариант 1 будет рабочим, а вариант 2 - ошибочным.

Третий вариант кроме кавычек, о которых я уже написал, имеет синтаксическую ошибку согласно
приведенной документации (ключ массива выделен кавычками, где этих кавычек не ожидается).

Кроме этого, в PHP есть ряд инструментов для безопасного формирования запросов, это

1. [prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php) для mysqli
2. [prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php), [bindParam()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php), [bindValue()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) для PDO

пользоваться лучше ими.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант правильный, но это не проверка, а просто выборка записи из базы данных. Осуществляется она по имени пользователя, который попытался авторизироваться на сайте стандартным методом (http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.http-auth.php).

Второй вариант не рабочий, т.к. передаваемое значение должно обрамляться одинарными кавычками (ибо строка).

Третий вариант тоже не правильный. А вообще, надо это делать так:

> $query = "SELECT pass FROM userlist
> WHERE name =
> {$_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER]}";

Comment: ваш вариант также будет не рабочим, т.к.

> т.к. передаваемое значение должно обрамляться одинарными кавычками (ибо строка).

я бы записал так:

    $query = "SELECT pass FROM userlist WHERE name = '{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}'";

но толкать в запрос непроверенные/неотфильтрованные данные в любом случае плохо